# Android Asynctask vs Service vs Scheduled jobs

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I kinda know the pro and cons of each of these.

I'm currently developping a RSS feed list, and for that use an asynctask.

I came across a fellow android developer that advised me to use a service, because asyntask is stopped in case the app is in the background.

But then I came to realise the update of an RSS feed isn't that important, therefore why would I slow down my users by running a service ?

I know scheduled job might also help regarding the device performance but once again is it really essential to update the RSS ?

Note : The importance of the content isn't relevant. I just try to understand if I'm forgetting about some essential practice that would justify a service.

**Bottom line** : When it comes to a task to relative importance (such as updating RSS feed), is it worth it to run a service that might slow down the device ? 
Can't we just use asynctask and admit it isn't critical if the app is put in the background ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as practices go you don't seem to have any other option than using an AsyncTask or a service. But let's look at it from another perspective than the importance of the RSS feed at hand. The amount of data transferred is probably low in comparison to bandwidth available to your device. So maybe the probability of your app going to background before your AsyncTask can update the RSS feed is too small. You can also start the AsynTask in onResume(), to make sure that whenever your app comes to foreground your data is up to date, and then check for updates on RSS feed periodically while on foreground.
 Sorry for long post but what I'm saying is that at the end the amount of resources you should use depends on you thoroughly studying your domain and your exact use case.